# Getting a ANY or ALL Error in Teradata SQL Code

Tags: sql, teradata, any, teradatasql

I have a Teradata SQL code

```
select SUM(col_A)/COUNT(col_A)
from table_A 
where col_B in (select col_C from table_B
                where col_D in ('1','2','3')
                and col_E = 'N'
                and col_F = 'AC'
                and col_G = to_date('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY')
                and col_H like ('P0','Q0')
                and col_I = 'Y'
                and col_J > 0
                and col_K between (current_date-90) and (current_date)
```

The subquery with col_C runs fine on its own, however when I run the full code, I am getting the

```
[Error 3785] [SQLState 42000] Expected ANY or ALL is missing error.
```

I don't understand why the error shows as I don't see any parenthesized list specified as the right operand of a comparison predicate.

Comment: `and col_H like ('P0','Q0')` needs to be `and col_H like any ('P0','Q0')`, or better yet `and col_H IN  ('P0','Q0')` since there is no wildcard search happening.

Comment: Also, you don't have the closing bracket for the subquery.